# Why doesn't this VisualForce Chart with data built in JavaScript render?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, charts, visualforce-charting

Currently looking at [Providing Chart Data via a JavaScript Array](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_providing_data_javascript_array.htm)

As per the example, data is embedded and returned by the JavaScript's dataArray property.

However, the chart does not seem to do anything with the data.

Here is my VisualForce page:

```
    <apex:page >
    <script>
        // Build the chart data array in JavaScript
        var dataArray = [
                         {'data1':33,'data2':66,'data3':80,'name':'Jan'},
                         {'data1':33,'data2':66,'data3':80,'name':'Feb'}
                       ];
    </script>
    <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="dataArray">
        <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name" />
        <apex:legend position="right" />
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apex:pieSeries renders a single set of values where each value can have a label. So this will render:

```
var dataArray = [
        {'data':33, 'name':'Jan'},
        {'data':66, 'name':'Feb'},
        {'data':80, 'name':'Mar'}
        ];
```

If you want multiple values at per label you will need to use e.g. a [bar chart](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_appearance_bar_charts.htm) where a comma-separated list of JSON field names are supported.

Comment: That works!  :-)